# Add Clear Button to Comment Field?

Tags: entities

Use Case: User wants to clear his comments to rewrite it.

When the User is populating the Comment field, I would like to offer a Clear or Cancel button that will remove the content.

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1**

1. Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a Clear or Cancel button/anchor tag(blank)
2. Add simple JS code to clear the fields

**OPTION 2**

1. Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a Clear or Cancel button/anchor tag(blank)
2. Use [Drupal AJAX Framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7)

**UPDATE**

You can use the `hook_form_alter()` inside your **template.php** file which is better based on your comment being more on the front-end side.

Next is you just need to get the ID of the form you want to alter/update by its form id value and just converting the dashes to underscores. An example would be:

```
<form id="leo-form">
  // form elements here
</form>
```

then you need to target it in your hook_form_alter() like so:

```
// Implements hook_form_alter.
function themename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'leo_form') {
    // place your code to add the clear button here
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind clearing the entire form, you could just do 1. Use hook_form_alter() to add <button type="reset" /> to the form.

Comment: That's awesome! I forgot about that. This solution is clean and straightforward than the options I've suggested.

Comment: Ok, am I to assume that I'm creating a custom module to use hook_form_alter ? I don't have significant custom dev exp. I more of a front-end GUI guy.

Comment: oh! thats alright too! i have updated my answer to suite your needs. hope it helps.